# Memory leak problem. iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, cocos2d-iphone, signals, sigbus

i've got a problem, i cannot solve it, just recieving error:

Program received signal:  “0”.

The Debugger has exited due to signal 10 (SIGBUS).The Debugger has exited due to signal 10 (SIGBUS).

Here is some method, if i comment it out, problem goes aways

```
- (void)loadTexture {
     const int num_tex = 10;
     glGenTextures(num_tex, &textures[0]);

     //TEXTURE #1
     textureImage[0] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wonder.jpg"].CGImage;
            //TEXTURE #2
     textureImage[1] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wonder.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #3
     textureImage[2] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall_eyes.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #4
     textureImage[3] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #5
     textureImage[4] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"books.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #6
     textureImage[5] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bush.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #7
     textureImage[6] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mushroom.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #8
     textureImage[7] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"roots.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #9
     textureImage[8] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"roots.jpg"].CGImage;
     //TEXTURE #10
     textureImage[9] = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clean.jpg"].CGImage; 

     for(int i=0; i<num_tex; i++) {
      NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage[i]);
      NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage[i]);
      GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);

      CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData,
                  texWidth, texHeight,
                  8, texWidth * 4,
                  CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage[i]),
                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
      CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth, (float)texHeight), textureImage[i]);
      CGContextRelease(textureContext);

      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

      glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

      free(textureData);
     }
 }
```

anyone can help me with releasing/deleting objects in this method? Thanks.

Comment: Step through the method. On which line does the error occur?

Comment: it's occur on 3-rd restart of the game, so, on the third (sometimes 4-th) time iPhone just close my app.

it feels like there is a huge memory leak hiding here

Comment: I don't see any memory leaks.

Comment: Do you mean it happens every 3 or 4 times you launch the app or every 3 or 4 times you restart something inside the app?

Comment: restart something inside the app, it's scene, cocos2d scene.

Answer (score 0):

[UIImage imagenamed:] creates memory leaks often.  I had a similar issue and fixed it by using the method found [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/).  Basically you want to use something like this:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/Image.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
UIImage *tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileName];
CGImageRef cg = [tmp CGImage];
[tmp release];
//Do stuff
CGImageRelease(cg);
```

Comment: textureImage[0] = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileName];

this line causing warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type. 


btw, textureImage is CGImageRef type.

Comment: What OS do you see leaks under BigJason? Have you reported this to Apple?

Comment: how can i release this thing: textureImage[9] = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fileName9] CGImage]; ?

Comment: you mean: CGImageRef cg = [m_image CGImage]; ? Cause There is no type called CGImage, or maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: BigJason, how can i contact you? Could you help me to selve this problem?

Comment: Is the code from my example not working for you?  Create the UIImage.  Grab the DBImageRef.  Release the UIImage.  Add the CGImageRef to your array.  When done with it call CGImageRelease.  There should be no more memory leaks if you follow that.

Comment: i did exactly what you said, nothing happens to my leak, it's still present :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to access any of the elements in the textureImage array outside the context of this method?

The elements in that array are being allocated and autoreleased by imageNamed:, but it looks like textureImage is defined outside the method.  If you attempt to call a method on any of the images in that array later on, you would see the error you're seeing.

If you do need the elements in the array elsewhere, be sure to retain the CGImage or UIImage objects here, and release them when you're done.

Comment: Hi, i'm not trying to access any element of textureImage outside this method. It's only here. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe i have to use glDeleteTextures() in the dealloc method? Just cant understand how to use it :(

Answer (score 0):

for all who will have such problem, just release your textures in dealloc, here is an example:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &textures[i]);
    }
```